# Create 3d bar for seaborn datasheets in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data-sheet Penguins and below is how I ploted 2d bar

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.barplot(data=df, x="island", y="body_mass_g",hue="sex",palette="Indigos")
```

Now I want to Plot 3Bar with matplotlib for same variables and Bellow is the code for same

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load the penguins data
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

# Select the data to plot
x = df['sex'].to_numpy()
y = df['island'].to_numpy()
z = np.zeros(len(x))
dx = np.ones(len(x))
dy = np.ones(len(x))
dz = df['bill_length_mm'].to_numpy()

# Create a figure and an axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the 3D bar chart
ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color="grey")

# Set the x, y, and z labels
ax.set_xlabel('Sex')
ax.set_ylabel('Island')
ax.set_zlabel('Bill length (mm)')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

But I am getting error
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that you are specifying a categorical variable in the 3D graph. So, I think we should add a new column of code that categorizes the categorical variable column and then, at the end, make it a scale of categorical variable names.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Load the penguins data
df = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
# category code add
df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
df['island_code'] = df['island'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['sex_code'] = df['sex'].astype('category').cat.codes

# Select the data to plot
x = df['sex_code'].to_numpy()
y = df['island_code'].to_numpy()
z = np.zeros(len(x))
dx = np.ones(len(x))
dy = np.ones(len(x))
dz = df['bill_length_mm'].to_numpy()

# Create a figure and an axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the 3D bar chart
ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color="grey")

# Set the x, y, and z labels
ax.set_xlabel('Sex')
ax.set_ylabel('Island')
ax.set_zlabel('Bill length (mm)')

ax.set_xticks([0.5, 1.5])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Male', 'Female'], va='baseline')

ax.set_yticks([0.5, 1.5, 2.5])
ax.set_yticklabels(['Biscoe', 'Dream', 'Torgersen'], va='baseline')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]